# Remove blue outline from Select box React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a React Material UI Select component in my project. I've managed to get most of the desired custom styles, but there is still a blue outline around the Select box when the dropdown paper is visible, or once an option has been selected and you move the mouse off the box (but it is still in focus). Which element do I need to target to remove the blue outline from the Select box? I've tried targeting various parts and using `outline: none` but I can't seem to find the solution. I've also read the React Material docs and searched Stackoverflow but can't find an answer. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is a demo of the Select box:

https://codesandbox.io/s/select-dropdown-hr7yx-hr7yx?file=/src/App.js

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  quantityRoot: {
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    backgroundColor: "#303039",
    opacity: 0.6,
    borderRadius: "5px",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#1E1E24",
      borderRadius: "5px",
      opacity: 1
    },
    "&:focus-within": {
      backgroundColor: "#1E1E24",
      borderRadius: "5px",
      opacity: 1
    },
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      border: "1px solid #484850"
    },
    "&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      border: "1px solid #484850"
    },
    "&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      border: "1px solid #484850",
      borderRadius: "5px 5px 0 0"
    },
    "& .Mui-disabled": {
      color: "#FFFFFF",
      opacity: 0.6
    },
    "& .Mui-disabled .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      border: "1px solid #484850"
    }
  },
  selectRoot: {
    color: "#FFFFFF"
  },
  icon: {
    color: "#FFFFFF"
  },
  selectPaper: {
    backgroundColor: "#1E1E24",
    border: "1px solid #484850",
    borderRadius: "5px",
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    "& li:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#303039"
    }
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FormControl
        variant="outlined"
        classes={{
          root: classes.quantityRoot
        }}
      >
        <Select
          classes={{
            root: classes.selectRoot,
            icon: classes.icon
          }}
          MenuProps={{ classes: { paper: classes.selectPaper } }}
          inputProps={{
            name: "gpuChildQuantity",
            id: "gpuChildQuantity"
          }}
        >
          {[...Array(8)].map((e, i) => {
            return (
              <MenuItem key={i} value={i + 1}>
                {i + 1}
              </MenuItem>
            );
          })}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just have a slight problem with your override of the "focused" styles.

You had:

```
    "&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      border: "1px solid #484850",
      borderRadius: "5px 5px 0 0"
    },
```

But `Mui-focused` is being added to a child of the `FormControl` rather than the `FormControl` itself (where this class is being applied), so `&.Mui-focused` doesn't ever match anything. Instead you need this to be similar to your override of the "disabled" styles. You need a space after the ampersand so that `.Mui-focused` targets a descendant of the `FormControl`:

```
    "& .Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      border: "1px solid #484850",
      borderRadius: "5px 5px 0 0"
    },
```

[image: Edit select-dropdown-hr7yx]

Answer (score 2):

A really simple fix to **remove all borders** from  mui Select dropdown.

Target the .CSS file **fieldset** tag:

```css
/* my css file */ 

fieldset{
    border: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
}

/* Don't forget to: import './mycssfile.css'; into your .js/jsx file
```

Although CSS styling and the !important tag is considered messy, this is the only way I debugged the issue. Spent far too long targeting styles, classes and global mui css classes in my .jsx files with no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks it's nice answer , for the others who like want it for Grid to use in Next.js or css without sass or scss can be use this code :

```
.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader:focus,
.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus {
     outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add **variant** attribute to get rid of the outline:

```
<Select variant="standard">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's late, but still,

States like hover, focus, disabled and selected, are styled with a higher CSS specificity. To customize them, you'll need to increase specificity.

```
.Button {
  color: black;
}

/* Increase the specificity */
.Button:disabled {
  color: white;
}

<Button disabled className="Button">
```

Here is [Material UI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#state-classes) about this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be removing the outline. It is bad for accessibility, it impacts keyboard only users that rely on the outline of interactive elements to know where they are positioned at.

A keyboard only user won't know that they have the select focused and won't know that they can activate it.

This affects a lot more people that we usually think and it's not ok to remove it just because it looks ugly.

Comment: Hello, I believe this should be a comment instead of an answer. It's a good comment as it takes accessibility into consideration, however it doesn't really answer the question. Besides, you don't really know if the OP is disabling it to make it look better or completely kill the accessibility, we just answer the technical side :)