# How to remove the border of the Material UI Select component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to customize the [Material UI `Select`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#main-content) component. Basically I just want to remove the border or rather the outline. I tried to [override](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61345288/9843082) the styles, tried to use a `NativeSelect` and tried to use a customized `InputBase` with the `Select` as *inputComponent* but none of this worked. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The border is applied to the label of the `OutlinedInput` component. Edit the css rule `notchedOutline` of the `OutlinedInput` component to remove the border. https://mui.com/api/outlined-input/#css

Answer (score 24):

I followed [@Bar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69860477/1419402): in my case I also had to reset the `box-shadow` applied over the `Select`.

For Material v5,

```
<Select sx={{ boxShadow: 'none', '.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': { border: 0 } }}>
```

[image: screenshot of a MUI select without borders]

Answer (score 20):

MUI exposes the `disableUnderline` prop in `Select` component. Just set it to `true`

Comment: This works, but first you need to set the `variant` to `standard`.

Answer (score 12):

I followed @cmolina 's answer, but still getting some border when the select is focused.

For Material v5, this works for me

```
<Select sx={{
                boxShadow: "none",
                ".MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": { border: 0 },
                "&.MuiOutlinedInput-root:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline":
                  {
                    border: 0,
                  },
                "&.MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline":
                  {
                    border: 0,
                  },
              }}
            >
```

Comment: You can remove it in one line `sx={{ '.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': { borderStyle: 'none' } }}` for all states

Comment: Best answer on this post ! thanks

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me was to use

- `disableUnderline` to remove the line below the selector
- `variant="standard"` to get rid of borders, both when the selector is focused or not.

Setting `'.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': { border: 0 }` will only remove borders of a selector when not focused.

Answer (score 2):

With "sx" you can access internal elements.

```
sx={{
  "& fieldset": {
    border: "none",
  },
}}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in CSS .
add the below code into your CSS, it really worked for me. Thanks

```
.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
  border: none ! important ;
}
```